# Can kotlin define dynamic method when class init?

Tags: methods, kotlin

My class:

```
class Demo {
    init {
        // define method here my some array:[a,b,c]
        // such as fun Demo.a,Demo.b...
    }
}
```

Function names are dynamic.

Can Kotlin do this?

Comment: You can declare a map from String (function name) to function, e. g. `Map<String, () -> Unit>`

Comment: good idea! @Miha_x64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't dynamically define functions in classes, but because functions are also objects, you can dynamically store them (in a field, array, map) and call them dynamically. Using some language features of Kotlin we can get a quite terse syntax:

```
class Demo(name: String) {
    private val functions: Map<String, () -> Any> = mapOf(name to { "Hello $name" })

    operator fun get(name: String): Any? = functions[name]?.invoke()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val demo = Demo("Kirill")

    println(demo["Kirill"])
}
```

Output:

> Hello Kirill

Answer (score 2):

No, Kotlin is a statically typed language. That means that the type every variable and method must be known at compile-time.